# How to save ApplicationUser as a foreign key in another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How to save ApplicationUser as a foreign key in another table

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace APP.Models
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Operador Document{ get; set; }
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace APP.Models
{
    public class Document
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DESC{ get; set; }
        public string SLUG{ get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserID")]
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When making the association:

```
AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@local.local");

Document doc = new Document();
doc.ID = 1;
doc.DESC= "DESC1";
doc.SLUG= "SLUG1";
doc.UserId = user;
```

But When I try to save it gives error:

**`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Document' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`**

someone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a value to a column that is **Identity** column. if you want to save **Id** by your key, you should enable **IDENTITY_INSERT** on `Document` Table.

By Executing this `sql` query you will set **IDENTITY_INSERT** to **ON** on `Document` table

```sql
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Document ON
```

Another option is remove your key.

```cs
AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@local.local");

Document doc = new Document();
doc.DESC= "DESC1";
doc.SLUG= "SLUG1";
doc.UserId = user;
```

In this case **Id** of Document table generated by **SQL** automatically